# Interface definition and generics. Should this be defined differently?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, generics

I have a class `Employee` and a class `Building`.
These classes are not related to each other from class hierarchy perspective.
I need to process a bunch of `Employee` and `Building` objects and their results will end up in different lists.
So I have and interface e.g.

```
public interface Processor{  
  public void process(String s, List<?> result);  
}
```

The idea is that the string `s` carries information related to either an `Employee` or a `Building` and the implementation after some processing adds to the result list either an `Employee` object or a `Building` object.
There are 2 implementations of `Processor` one is `EmployeeProcessor` and a `BuildingProcessor`.
Somewhere in the code I get a reference to either of these and I pass either a `List<Employee>` or a `List<Building>` to the `process` method.

Problem is that the code does not compile.
When I do e.g. inside the `EmployeeProcessor` : `result.add(new Employee(a,b,c,d));`
I get:

> The method add(capture#2-of ?) in the type List is not
>   applicable for the arguments

I guess I can understand the problem, but I don't want to change the interface to:

```
public interface Processor{  
  public process(String s, List result);  
}
```

I.e. not specify type of list.
Is there a way around this problem? Is the interface definition wrong?
Note: this interface is part of implementation of `Command` pattern

Comment: 1. Post the whole error message. 2. Post your actual code - not snippets that are not even valid Java...

Comment: @thkala:1) No error message. Eclipse compiler indication 2)What do you mean not valid java?

Comment: 1. That's not an "indication". That's a full-blown compiler error message. 2. `public process(String s, List result);` is not a valid method declaration - there is no return type...

Comment: 1. I have posted the compiler error 2. I apologize for that. You are right. My bad

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I was thinking.

```
interface Processor<T>{
    public void process(String s, List<T> result);
}

class BuildingProcessor implements Processor<Building>{
    @Override
    public void process(String s, List<Building> result) {
        result.add(new Building());
    }
}

class EmployeeProcessor implements Processor<Employee>{
    @Override
    public void process(String s, List<Employee> result) {
        result.add(new Employee());
    }
}
```

FYI, you can further limit the type. For example, if both `Building` and `Employee` classes implement, lets say, `Processable`, then you can do `interface Processor<T extends Processable>`